# Can i Add an image ontop a <div> without adding any html tag?

Tags: css, background, z-index

lets say we have

```
<div class="picture"><img class="picture_thumb" src="path" /> </div>
```

And i'd like to use CSS to add an image `z-index` higher to `.picture` (it's basically an magnifying glass Icon so I can see it on top of `.picture_thumb`)

Any chance?

Thanks a lot

PD: it would be like instead of a background, a Front-ground
-EDIT-
An image so you can understand better
[image]

Comment: Which browsers/versions do you need to support? You can do this with only CSS if you don't need to support IE6/7.

Comment: I need them all... but just to know, how could I do it? thanks!!

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling you needed to support them. If you didn't need IE6/7, you could have done it using `:before`, in a similar fashion to how it was used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884320/simple-css-beforehover-not-working-csslint-no-errors/6884335#6884335).

Comment: I can avoid IE6, unfortunatelly not IE7 -interesting link, thanks-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as front-ground.

You'd have to do something like this:

```
<div class="picture">
  <img src="images/picture.jpg" alt="Picture" />
  <img class="magnifier" src="images/magnifier.jpg" alt="Maginfy" />
</div>

.picture {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.magnifier {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

You could also do it with javascript if you didn't want to add the magnifier image to each picture div.

Comment: so there is not a chance i can Do it with only CSS, right? i need to add the <img> or any element with the bg image, right? thanks!